# Bootstrap: Dropdown Select FORM - 2 columns

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, list, multiple-columns, dropdown

I have a question. I want to make dropdown select list in bootstrap, but with 2 columns. In this moment it looks like this:

[image: Here is the photo]

```css
.form-select-vidconvert {
    border-radius: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<select class="form-control form-select-vidconvert">
  
  <optgroup label="Category 1">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </optgroup>

  <optgroup label="Category 2">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </optgroup>

</select>

</div>
      </div>
```

I've spend 2 days to figure it out. In internet I found only 2 columns for dropdown menu (methods from there doesn't work for select list forms). How can I do this?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by 2 columns for dropdown menu?

Comment: I found this: http://alijafarian.com/demos/bootstrap-multi-column-dropdown-menu/

There is method for making multiple columns in Dropdown Menu, but I need to make multiple columns (in this case two) in Dropdown List - like this: [link] http://vpx.pl/i/2017/01/12/lista-good.jpg [link]

Comment: You shouldn't use select tag for that (because you can't style dropdown menu). There are tons of tutorials on the web how to create dropdown menu with HTML/CSS/JS (also with multiple columns).

Answer (score 0):

My solution to a similar problem was to set on [**`bootstrap-select`**](https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/). This is a highly flexible multiselect option for bootstrap.

[image: screenshot]

The second trick is to use `flex` with `flex-direction: columns` to define the columns and use the `.divide` class (which is generated when using `optgroup`) to set a new line.

***Note** flex columns needs a fixed height to work correctly, so you need an idea how many elements are in each column.*

```js
$('.form-select-vidconvert').selectpicker();
```

```css
.row {
    padding: 8px 20px;
    min-height: 200px
}

.form-select-vidconvert {
    border-radius: 18px;
}


.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-menu {
    height: 160px !important;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-menu.open > .dropdown-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%; /* has to be set for the divider to work */
}

.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-menu.open > .dropdown-menu li {
    flex-grow: 0;                
    width: 50%;
}

.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-menu.open > .dropdown-menu li.divider {
    //outline: 1px dotted red; /* debug */
    flex-basis: 100%;
    width: 0;
    height: unset;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.12.4/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.12.4/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<select class="form-control form-select-vidconvert" title="Multiselect example with two columns">
  
  <optgroup label="Category 1">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </optgroup>

  <optgroup label="Category 2">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </optgroup>

</select>

</div>
</div>
```